# ¿Cómo mostrar los valores más altos de una lista en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo mi código el cual necesito mostrar el ganador o en todo caso los ganadores, sé que se puede hacer en un `for` in a mi lista pero no se muy bien la lógica:

```
repetir=1
while repetir == 1:
    numerodeveces=int(input("Numero participantes: "))
    for i in range(numerodeveces):
        nombre = input("\n Nombre del binguero %s : " % (i+1))
        tarjeta_bingo = listaAleatorios()
        dicci=dict()
        puntaje = 0
        dicci['nombre'] = nombre
        dicci['tarjeta_bingo'] = tarjeta_bingo
        dicci['puntaje'] = puntaje 
        print('{} tiene la cartilla: '.format(dicci.get('nombre')))
        distribuir_grilla(tarjeta_bingo, 3)
        participantes.append(dicci)
    bolos=tandabolos()
    print('0=======================Empiesa el juego=======================0')
    print('La tanda de bolos es: \n')
    distribuir_grilla(bolos, 15)
```

Ese es todo mi código pero al final no se como jalar los resultados de los ganadores incluso había creado una función para mostrar el valor mas alto el cual es:

```
def mostrar_ganador(participantes):
    ganador=''
    valorMasAlto=0
    for d in participantes:
        if d['puntaje']>valorMasAlto:
            valorMasAlto = d['puntaje']
            ganador = d['nombre']
    return ganador, valorMasAlto
```

Pero no se como mandarlo al final de todo mi código, como menciono quiero mostrar el o los ganadores al final.

Comment: Añadelos a una lista y devuelve esa lista!

Answer (score 1):

El retorno de tu función es `return ganador, valorMasAlto`, esto en realidad es azúcar sintáctico para retornar una tupla, es decir, equivale a `return (ganador, valorMasAlto)`.

Por lo que si asignas a una variable el retorno de tu función, dicha variable acabará apuntando a una tupla de dos elementos:

```
participantes = [{'nombre': 'Juan', 'tarjeta_bingo': 5, 'puntaje': 15},
                 {'nombre': 'Laura', 'tarjeta_bingo': 2, 'puntaje': 10},
                 {'nombre': 'Pedro', 'tarjeta_bingo': 1, 'puntaje': 3},
                 {'nombre': 'Raquel', 'tarjeta_bingo': 4, 'puntaje': 20}
                 ]

def mostrar_ganador(participantes):
    ganador = ''
    valorMasAlto = 0
    for d in participantes:
        if d['puntaje'] > valorMasAlto:
            valorMasAlto = d['puntaje']
            ganador = d['nombre']
    return ganador, valorMasAlto

ganador = mostrar_ganador(participantes)
nombre = ganador[0]
puntos = ganador[1]
print(f"El ganador es {nombre} con {puntos} puntos")
```

No obstante, puedes simplemente desempaquetar la tupla:

```
nombre, puntos = mostrar_ganador(participantes)
print(f"El ganador es {nombre} con {puntos} puntos")
```

Si lo deseas puedes usas el built-in `max` para obtener el diccionario con la clave puntaje con mayor valor:

```
import operator

def mostrar_ganador(participantes):
    ganador = max(participantes, key=operator.itemgetter("puntaje"))
    return ganador["nombre"], ganador["puntaje"]

nombre, puntaje = mostrar_ganador(participantes)
print(f"El ganador es {nombre} con {puntos} puntos")
```

básicamente obtiene el diccionario mayor de la lista, teniendo en cuenta para ordenarlos el valor asociado a la clase `puntaje` exclusivamente. De esto se encarga el argumento `key`, que le indica que por cada diccionario de la lista obtenga el valor de la clave `puntaje` (`operator.itemgetter("puntaje")`) y lo use para comparar ese diccionario con los demás.

Ahora bien, si tienes más de un jugador con la máxima puntuación, la función solo te retorna uno de ellos. Puedes solucionarlo de varias formas, por ejemplo, modificando la función para que retorne una lista de tuplas con los datos de todos los participantes con la máxima puntuación:

```
participantes = [{'nombre': 'Juan', 'tarjeta_bingo': 5, 'puntaje': 15},
                 {'nombre': 'Laura', 'tarjeta_bingo': 2, 'puntaje': 20},
                 {'nombre': 'Pedro', 'tarjeta_bingo': 1, 'puntaje': 3},
                 {'nombre': 'Raquel', 'tarjeta_bingo': 4, 'puntaje': 20}
                 ]

def mostrar_ganador(participantes):
    ganadores = []
    max_punt = 0
    for participante in participantes:
        puntos = participante["puntaje"]
        if puntos > max_punt:
            max_punt = puntos
            ganadores = [(participante['nombre'], puntos)]
        elif puntos == max_punt:
            ganadores.append((participante['nombre'], puntos))
    return  ganadores

for nombre, puntos in mostrar_ganador(participantes):
    print(f"El ganador es {nombre} con {puntos} puntos")
```

Se podría usar tu función original y aplicar un filtro a la lista, pero el problema es que iteramos dos veces sobre ella cuando podemos hacerlo iterando una sola vez:

```
_, max_pun = mostrar_ganador(participantes)
ganadores = [(participante["nombre"], participante["puntaje"])
                for participante in participantes if participante["puntaje"] == max_pun]

for nombre, puntos in ganadores:
    print(f"El ganador es {nombre} con {puntos} puntos")
```

Comment: pregunto, y si se repiten los puntajes me mostraria los maximos los 2 o solo 1?

Comment: Paulo mira al final de la respuesta, la he editado,  se me olvido ese punto... :(

Comment: FJSevilla me sale este error `print(f"El ganador es {nombre} con {puntos} puntos")
        ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block`

Comment: El código en mi ejemplo está bien identado, debes tener mal tu identación como resultado de pegar el código. El `print` debe estar dentro del `for` como está en mi código, posiblemente lo tengas al mismo nivel, eso explicaría el error.

Comment: Consulta acá este guion abajo a quien hace referencia _, max_pun = mostrar_ganador(participantes)

Comment: Es solo una convención en Python, cuando necesitamos asignar un valor a una variable que no vamos a usar nunca para nada se usa un guión bajo como nombre de esa variable. En este caso, el nombre del ganador no nos interesa, pero para poder desempaquetar la tupla necesitamos asignar su primer elemento  a algo. Por ejmplo, cuando usamos un `for`  con `range` para iterar x veces pero no nos interesa el número de la iteración se hace `for _ in range(5)`, no `for i in range(5)` si no vamos a usar `i` nunca.

Comment: Muy interesante muchas gracias amigo Sevilla aclarado totalmente